# How to Optimize Diagonal Movement Code for Chess Engine?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, chess, try-except

I'm currently in the process of building my own chess engine and could really use some suggestions on how to make this segment of code for calculating diagonal moves more efficient. (This is obviously only for diagonals going Up-Right)

As of now I'm using "Try-Except" to iterate by 1, and then my return statement filters out any off-board values. However this seems like a very bulky way of doing things.

Any comments or advice on how to refactor this code would be greatly appreciated.

```
import argparse, json

chessBoard = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] for i in range(8)]

chess_map_from_alpha_to_index = {
    "a" : 0,
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : 2,
    "d" : 3,
    "e" : 4,
    "f" : 5,
    "g" : 6,
    "h" : 7
}

chess_map_from_index_to_alpha = {
    0: "a",
    1: "b",
    2: "c",
    3: "d",
    4: "e",
    5: "f",
    6: "g",
    7: "h"
}


def getBishopMoves(pos, chessBoard):
    column, row = list(pos.strip().lower())
    row = int(row) - 1
    column = chess_map_from_alpha_to_index[column]
    i,j = row, column
    solutionMoves = []

#Up-Right Diagonal
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 1][j + 1]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 1, j + 1])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 2][j + 2]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 2, j + 2])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 3][j + 3]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 3, j + 3])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 4][j + 4]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 4, j + 4])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 5][j + 5]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 5, j + 5])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 6][j + 6]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 6, j + 6])
    except:
        pass
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 7][j + 7]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 7, j + 7])
    except:
        pass    
    try:
        temp = chessBoard[i + 7][j + 7]
        solutionMoves.append([i + 7, j + 7])
    except:
        pass   

    temp = [i for i in solutionMoves if i[0] >=0 and i[1] >=0]
    solutionMoves = ["".join([chess_map_from_index_to_alpha[i[1]], str(i[0] + 1)]) for i in temp]
    solutionMoves.sort()
    return solutionMoves
```

Comment: You could put your `try:...except:pass` blocks into a `for` loop at least. It would stop problems like duplication (as you have with the 7s)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because generic requests for improvement of working code belong on [codereview.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. I will make sure to read the guidelines more closely.

Answer (score 0):

For the bishop, four different directions have to be considered: up-right, down-right, down-left, up-left. For all four options, you can find the maximum projected coordinates for each, and then iterate towards all. If another piece is encountered during the iteration, the looping stops. A possible implementation of this algorithm is below:

```
board = [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', 'b', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'], 
         ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
options = [lambda x, y:(x+1, y+1), lambda x, y:(x+1, y-1), lambda x, y:(x-1, y-1), lambda x, y:(x-1, y+1)]
projected = [lambda x, y:(x+min([x,y]), y+min([x,y])), lambda x, y:(x+min([x,y]), y-min([x,y])), lambda x, y:(x-min([x,y]), y-min([x,y])), lambda x, y:(x-min([x,y]), y+min([x,y]))]
def iterate_towards(current, to, func):
   while current != to:
      current = list(func(*current))
      if board[current[0]][current[-1]] != '-':
        break
      yield current
   yield to

def get_bishop_moves(current:list):
   for a, b in zip(options, projected):
      yield list(iterate_towards([3, 4], list(b(*current)), a))

print(list(get_bishop_moves([3, 4])))
```

Output:

```
[[[4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]], [[4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1]], [[2, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1]], [[2, 5], [1, 6], [0, 7]]]
```